# como faço para colocar um Scrollbar em uma janela no python como se fosse uma pagina web, quanto mais conteudo mais poderia descer pela Scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Queria que ao entrar na janela do programa usando tkinter, fosse possivel usar um Scrollbar para procurar mais items da janela para que não fique com sua altura limitada, podendo arrastar a scrollbar para baixo (Vertical Apenas), para encontrar mais items na janela

Já criei o Scrollbar mas não sei a quem atribuir

```
jan = Tk()
jan.geometry('1360x760')


lbl = Label("TEXTOS COM NOME DE PRODUTOS")
lbl.place(x=500, y=200)

nao sei como atribuir o scrollbar a isso

sb1=Scrollbar(jan)
sb1.place(x=1330, y=110)
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nisso](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm) @Marcos

Comment: Algo parecido com isto ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v1VNlV14aw

Answer (score 1):

No tkinter, frames não podem ser rolados. A solução é criar um `Canvas` e colocar outro frame dentro dele.

Essa classe `JanelaRolavel` é um `Frame` que contém um `Canvas` com outro `Frame` dentro. Basta colocar seus objetos neste "subframe" (que está no atributo `.conteudo`) e eles vão ser roláveis:

```
import tkinter as t

class JanelaRolavel(t.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        t.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)            

        # cria um canvas e uma barra de rolagem para rolá-lo:
        rolagem = t.Scrollbar(self, orient=t.VERTICAL)
        rolagem.pack(fill=t.Y, side=t.RIGHT, expand=t.FALSE)
        self.canvas = t.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=rolagem.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=t.LEFT, fill=t.BOTH, expand=t.TRUE)
        rolagem.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # reseta a visão:
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # cria um frame dentro do canvas
        # para que seja rolado junto com ele:
        self.conteudo =  t.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.id_conteudo = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.conteudo, anchor=t.NW)

        # cria eventos para detectar mudanças no canvas
        # e sincronizar com a barra de rolagem:
        self.conteudo.bind('<Configure>', self._configurar_conteudo)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configurar_canvas)

    def _configurar_conteudo(self, evento):
            # atualiza a barra de rolagem para o tamanho do frame de conteudo:
            tamanho = (
                self.conteudo.winfo_reqwidth(),
                self.conteudo.winfo_reqheight()
            )
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % tamanho)
            if self.conteudo.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                # atualizar tambem a largura do canvas para caber o conteudo:
                self.canvas.config(width=self.conteudo.winfo_reqwidth())

    def _configurar_canvas(self, evento):
        if self.conteudo.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
            # atualizar tambem a largura do conteudo para preencher o canvas:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(
                self.id_conteudo, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
```

Segue agora um exemplo usando essa classe para fazer esta janela:

[image: Exemplo]

Código:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Exemplo(t.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            t.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            self.frame = JanelaRolavel(self)
            self.frame.pack(fill=t.BOTH)
            for i in range(10): # cria botoes no frame interno
                t.Button(self.frame.conteudo, 
                    text="Botão {}".format(i)).pack(fill=t.BOTH)

    app = Exemplo()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Depende do que  quiser fazer, um `tkinter.ListBox` já pode prover toda a funcionalidade desejada, sem precisar do Canvas intermediário.  @Marcos: não deixe de olhar a documentação do ListBox também - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm